# NSNotification not receiving in View Controller from appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

hello i assign nsnotifiaction in app delegate.m's method and this method call eprox every 30sec, and i wants its notifcation in viewcontroller adn execute method,
here is my code of appdelegate .m

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    BOOL yy=    self.bannerView.bannerLoaded;
    if (yy==1){
        self.iAdString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1"];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BannerViewActionWillBegin" object:self];
     }
   else{
      self.iAdString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"0"];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BannerViewActionDidFinish" object:self];
     }
}
```

and in viewcontroller.m

//i defined in viewdidload method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:@"BannerViewActionWillBegin "object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:) name:@"BannerViewActionDidFinish" object:nil];
}
```

its method are..

```
- (void)willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self.view addSubview:self.app.bannerView];
     NSLog(@"come");
}

- (void)didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
     NSLog(@"come");
    [self.app.bannerView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

I have not getting response of excessing method while method read in appdelegate file.

Please help me.

Comment: in applegate show an alertview whenever you recive an alert and make that alertview subview to windows so that we will get alert with respective of the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo error.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:@"BannerViewActionWillBegin "object:nil];

//Your error here-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

**You have put a space there.**

*SideNote:* For all notification names, you should/can create a separate file and put all your notification names as constants strings.

```
const NSString *kBannerViewActionWillBegin=@"BannerViewActionWillBegin";
```

this will be easier to change the value and no such typo will happen.

Comment: thank you very much, small mistake creating big headache .i like your recommendations and answers very much .

Comment: This is what I learnt from SO. Thanks to my un-met Teachers here.

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I get is except for the notification name's all other stuff is fine, did you check whether the notification gets fired. Try keeping break points at the notification firing line.